# ios objective c small notification banner for no internet connection and back to online same like youtube app for iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, banner

I want to implement a bottom bar banner for no internet connection same like youtube app. I am not able to find any solution please help if anybody have idea about it.

Comment: change tabbar frame (y position) if no reachibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify change status that is, when a app is connected or disconnected or changed(wifi to data) network using reachability.

Look at this official Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Using Reachability you can recognize the type of your connection.

There is also an example on how detect the network changes.

According to detected changes you simply have to trigger UI in main thread which will show you banner in bottom.

Note - Your question is very broad and if you google a little bit more you'll get your answer easily. Let me know if you need further help in this.

Comment: I already using Reachability. I need help to show banner like youtube.